# Laravel 5.2, get ID of parent article when creating additions

Tags: laravel

I have an application, and I want to be able to add different elements too the article, like Polls/questions and such. For this, I want the questions to get the article ID from the previous page, when I go to the create function, as the article ID will be referenced in the question DB, so that the questions can all be called into the articles page. How do I take the ID from the articles through to the page with the create question form, so that the data can be stored on the questions DB with the ID for the article going into the article_id table. So far i can edit the article, using the edit function in the controller, so it can be like:

```
localhost.com/article/5/edit
```

But I ideally want it so that after clicking an 'add question/poll' button on the page, it will take me to:

```
localhost.com/article/5/question/create
```

And can have a hidden form field that can add the article_id into it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use model binding for that, in you questions controller where the question form `POST`s the data, you can have:

```
public function create(Article $article)
{
    dd($article->id);
}
```

not only you'll have the article id, you'll have the whole article object, where you can create the question form the relation method on the article object (assuming you have one):

```
$article->questions->create($data);
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure I get what you mean... Currently my create function calls the Question table ($questions = Question::all();) and the user table in the same way, and passes them to the create view... Would putting the (dd($article->id);) in the create function pass an article ID to it? And if so, how does it know that it is the right ID for the article I want to add the question to?